# How do I fix this small memory leak for my program?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, destructor

So I made a program that simulates a Tic-Tac-Toe game and ran it with valgrind and it says that I have a memory leak. What is causing this leak and how do I fix it?

Here is the output from valgrind:

```
==15253== 
==15253== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15253==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==15253==   total heap usage: 37 allocs, 36 frees, 76,864 bytes allocated
==15253== 
==15253== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==15253==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15253==    by 0x4EC5B1F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==15253==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==15253==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==15253==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==15253==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==15253== 
==15253== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15253==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15253==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15253==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15253==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==15253==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15253== 
==15253== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15253== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

And here is the code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/Board.h"

using namespace std;

/**
 * Main function that is run.
 * @return: 0 on exit success
 */
int main() {
    Board b;
    int r, c;
    int moveCount = 0;

    cout << "* * * * * Welcome to the Tic-Tac-Toe game! * * * * *" << endl;
    cout << "Enter numbers 1, 2, or 3 when prompted for coordinates of your move." << endl;
    cout << b.toString() << endl;

    // Loops until there are no more possible moves.
    while(moveCount < 9) {
        // Prompts for coordinates to make a move.
        do {
            if(moveCount % 2 == 0) {
                cout << "Player X's turn, enter the row and column of your move.\nRow #:";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Player O's turn, enter the row and column of your move.\nRow #:";
            }
            cin >> r;
            cout << "Column #:";
            cin >> c;

            // Checks if the move is valid.
            if(b.canPut((r - 1), (c - 1)) != 1) {
                cout << "\nInvalid move, re-enter the desired coordinates.\n" << endl;
            }
        }while(b.canPut((r - 1), (c - 1)) != 1);

        // Makes the move.
        if(moveCount % 2 == 0) {
            b.makeMove((r - 1), (c - 1), X);
        }
        else {
            b.makeMove((r - 1), (c - 1), O);
        }

        cout << b.toString() << endl;

        // Checks if there is a winner and breaks the loop if there is.
        if(b.checkWinner() != 0)
            break;
        moveCount++;
    }

    // Prints the appropriate statement base on the winning status, if any.
    if(moveCount == 9) {
        cout << "\nGame over, stalemate." << endl;
    }
    else {
        if(b.checkWinner() == X) {
            cout << "\nPlayer X has won!!!" << endl;
        }
        else if(b.checkWinner() == O) {
            cout << "\nPlayer O has won!!!" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Board.h:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <string>
#define X 1
#define O 5
#define SIZE 3

/**
 * Board class for tic-tac-toe project.
 */
class Board {
    private:
        int **grid;
    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();
        int checkWinner();
        int canPut(int r, int c);
        void makeMove(int r, int c, int val);
        std::string toString();
};

#endif
```

Board.cpp:

```
#include "../include/Board.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/**
 * Constructor for a Board object.
 */
Board::Board() {
    grid = new int*[SIZE];

    // Creates all the 1D arrays to make the 2D array.
    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < SIZE; ctr++) {
        grid[ctr] = new int[SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            grid[ctr][i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Destructor for a Board object.
 */
Board::~Board() {
    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < SIZE; ctr++) {
        delete[] grid[ctr];
    }
    delete[] grid;
}

/**
 * Checks if there is a winner for the current game.
 * @return: 0 if no winner, X if X player wins or O if O player wins
 */
int Board::checkWinner() {
    int sum;

    // Checks all the rows for a winner.
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for(int ctr = 0; ctr < SIZE; ctr++) {
            sum += grid[i][ctr];
        }
        if(sum == 3) {
            return X;
        }
        else if(sum == 15) {
            return O;
        }
    }

    // Checks all the columns for a winner.
    for(int a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
        sum = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < SIZE; b++) {
            sum += grid[b][a];
        }
        if(sum == 3) {
            return X;
        }
        else if(sum == 15) {
            return O;
        }
    }

    // Checks the top-left to bottom-right diagonal for a winner.
    sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        sum += grid[i][i];
    }
    if(sum == 3) {
        return X;
    }
    else if(sum == 15) {
        return O;
    }

    // Checks the top-right to bottom-left diagonal for a winner.
    sum = 0;
    for(int r = 0, c = SIZE - 1; r < SIZE && c > 0; r++, c--) {
        sum += grid[r][c];
    }
    if(sum == 3) {
        return X;
    }
    else if(sum == 15) {
        return O;
    }

    // Returns zero because after checking all the possibilities, a winner has not been found.
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Determines if there is an open spot on the board at the given coordinates.
 * @param r: the row to be checked
 * @param c: the column to be checked
 * @return: 1 if there is an open spot, 0 if not
 */
int Board::canPut(int r, int c) {
    if(grid[r][c] == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Simulates making a move for a player.
 * @param r: the row to set the value
 * @param c: the column to set the value
 * @param val: the value to be set at the given coordinates
 */
void Board::makeMove(int r, int c, int val) {
    grid[r][c] = val;
}

/**
 * Creates a representation of the board as a string.
 * @return: string of the board
 */
string Board::toString() {
    char a, b, c;
    string output = "Board:\n";

    // Loops through every line for the 2D array.
    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < SIZE; ctr++) {

        // Loops through every value of the 1D array being checked.
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            output += ' ';
            if(grid[ctr][i] == X) {
                output += 'X';
            }
            else if(grid[ctr][i] == O) {
                output += 'O';
            }
            else {
                output += ' ';
            }
            if(i != (SIZE - 1)) {
                output.append(" |");
            }   
            else {
                output += '\n';
            }
        }

        // Pads each line with a line of '-' characters.
        if(ctr != (SIZE - 1)) {
            for(int i = 0; i < (SIZE * 4) - 1; i++) {
                output += '-';
            }
            output += '\n';
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, that memory leak isn't your problem. It's a memory leak incurred when the program is doing initialization, before any of your code is even executed.

Valgrind typically ignores these. It has a file that has a list of things it needs to ignore in various libraries on various platforms. Perhaps you used a Valgrind option that told it to not ignore them, or perhaps it just hasn't been set up correctly for that exact version of libstdc++ on that platform.

As an unrelated C++ style note, I will say that I don't really like that you used `#define` in *Board.h*. You should be declaring things `const`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Why do you say I shouldn't use `#define` in Board.h? I am new to C++ so I am not used to common conventions of the language.

Comment: @AnthonyPalumbo - The preprocessor is... well, considered ugly. Use it for `#include` and (if absolutely necessary) conditional compilation (`#if` and `#ifdef` and such). Using `#define` is ugly because it completely tramples the scope rules and the type rules and various other things. C++ has inline functions. And you can say things like `const int foo = 5;` instead of `#define foo 5` and `foo` now has a type and is treated like a proper identifier with a scope. Why the preprocessor is to be avoided is kind of complex actually.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good but I would suggest not using the pointer of pointer for grid, which is a bit tricky to handle.
Instead of `int **grid`,
have `int grid[SIZE][SIZE]`.
Then you don't need any new and delete calls - no source of memory leak!
This works unless the SIZE is very big and you try to allocate Board on stack. If the SIZE is big, just allocate Board on heap by `b = new Board()`. (Don't forget to delete it!)